# How to design a secure shopping cart with guest handling?

Tags: php, mysql, security, yii, shopping-cart

**Working environment**: PHP5 object oriented, MVC patern, Yii Framework

**Shopping cart**: List of products with a quantity and a price for each. The role of the shipping cart is only to put products in it and if the user wants to purchase items then:

- *if guest*: register/login
- *if member*: shopping cart sent to validation controller to validate / update the cart with all payment / shipping options as you could
  think (coupon / billing address, shopping address etc.)

---

Shopping cart handle:

- add / remove product
- on timeout > clear from itself

Shopping cart do not handle:

- discount / coupon
- all payment & billing process

---

**The question is**: how to design it to be efficient and secure?

## Option 1

Create a sql table and store:

- PHPSESSID from session_id()
- item_id
- quantity
- unit_price
- datetime (refreshed each time the shopping cart is updated)

Create an event on mysql to delete each rows with a datetime > 30 mins.

Then to get the shopping cart you get all items from table with the current session id and create a foreach() to get them all.

## Option 2

Save all shopping cart information in a cookie

---

On my point of view Option 1 is more secure than Option 2 but consume more ressource and may expose the SQL database to attacks (create massive new sessions that overflow the database).
Option 2 is exposed to cookie injection but takes less ressource and expose information to users.

Is there any other / better way to do it?

Comment: Store the data into the DB since you will want to know what your customers AND visitors do with their shopping carts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply assign a [`$_SESSION["shoppingCart"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) array which contains `quantity` and `item_id`? For example:

```
$_SESSION["shoppingCart"] = array(
   $item_id => $quantity
);
```

And then, when processing the shopping cart, call a method which collects all required data from the database, based on the stored `item_id`. You can then proceed to calculate the actual shopping cart prices.

This way, when the `$_SESSION` expires, you don't have to trigger any events in your database. If you want to save the `$_SESSION`, you could save this in the database as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Informations are not shown to users and it's not heavy for my server, perfect!